# PHP fwrite writing empty file

Tags: php, file-io, fwrite

I'm trying to make this save a file and it creates the file, but it's always empty. This is the code for it:

```
<?php

$code = htmlentities($_POST['code']);

$i = 0;
$path = 'files/';
$file_name = '';

while(true) {
    if (file_exists($path . strval($i) . '.txt')) {
        $i++;
    } else {
        $name = strval($i);
        $file_name = $path . $name . '.txt';
        break;
    }
}

fopen($file_name, 'w');
fwrite($file_name, $code);
fclose($file_name);

header("location: index.php?file=$i");

?>
```

I echoed out $code to make sure it wasn't empty, and it wasn't. I also tried replacing

```
fwrite($file_name, $code);
```

with this:

```
fwrite($file_name, 'Test');
```

and it was still empty. I have written to files a couple of times before in PHP, but I'm still really new to PHP and I have no idea whats wrong. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading/Writing to/from a file or stream requires a resource handle:

```
$resource = fopen($file_name, 'w');
fwrite($resource, $code);
fclose($resource);
```

The resource handle `$resource` is essentially a pointer to the open file/stream resource. You interact with the created resource handle, not the string representation of the file name.

This concept also exists with [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) as well. This is a common practice in PHP, especially since PHP didn't have support for OOP when these methods came to be.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of the [samples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) on php.net

Comment: Oh thanks haha, I realized I forgot to set a variable for the file I created.